# Explicit transaction in Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Does anybody know how to create an explicit transaction in Entity Framework 7 ???
All the info I find is refered to the version 6 of EF. The documentation is also very incomplete so, could anybody provide an example of it?

I have a dbContext and I must delete an entity and it's related objects, and then insert them again, but in the same transaction, so I'll always have a "version" of the rows.

Comment: Could you include small code fragment where you want to use transaction? Do you have some `dbContext` or `DbCommand`? Typically one should use `using (context.Database.BeginTransaction()) {.../*do something*/...}`, but one can use `await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync()` instead. One can use `using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) {...}` and call `transaction.Commit()` explicitly to commit transaction or call `transaction.Rollback()` for rollback.  There are exist more exotic [EnlistTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254973(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Not so exotic... yet ;-)  So, the bytes are the same than in EF6? Then I've missed something. I have a dbContext and I must delete an entity and it's related objects, and then insert them again.

Comment: Ok, your code works, but it's the same than EF6. Do you mind if I delete the question or prefer I edit it and you post your comment as answer?

Comment: I'll post short answer. I hope it will help other people.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The transaction functionality are included in EF7 starting with RC1 only (see [the statement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/11/18/entity-framework-7-rc1-available.aspx)). The call of `.SaveChanges()` (or `.SaveChangesAsync()`) should use automatic transaction. Then I suppose that the state of some items of the entities should be marked as Deleted before, for example.

One can start transaction explicitly by wrapping some fragment of manipulation on the database inside of

```cs
using (context.Database.BeginTransaction()) {
    /*do something*/
}
```

The transaction will be committed by call of `.Dispose()` at the end of `using` block. One can use alternatively

```cs
using (var transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync()) {
    /*do something*/
    /*one can call
       transaction.Rollback() or transaction.Commit()
      explicitly in the code */
}
```

It general all should looks like in previous version of Entity Framework. See [the post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx) for example.

Comment: This is not in RC-1 final, needs newer version of DatabaseFacade.

Comment: @user764754: Do you verified this? Look at [the test](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/7.0.0-rc1/test/EntityFramework.Relational.FunctionalTests/TransactionTestBase.cs#L62) for example included in RC1. It uses `BeginTransaction()`

Comment: In RC-1 it's an extension method in EntityFramework.Relational. Later it's with DatabaseFacade in EntityFramework.Core. I'm referencing only core RC-1 that's why I didn't find it.

Comment: @user764754: Do you mean the source code of EF RC1? Look at [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/7.0.0-rc1/src/EntityFramework.Relational/RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.cs#L75-L90) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/7.0.0-rc1/src/EntityFramework.Relational/Storage/RelationalConnection.cs#L90-L142)